# What differences are there between Chia and Flax Eggs?

Tags: eggs, vegetarian, vegan, flax, chia

In substituting Flax Eggs (milled/ground flax seeds in a water slurry, after they congeal) for regular eggs, I have found them to be a versatile aide in baking and thickening any number of dishes.

I have begun to hear tell of using chia seeds instead of flax or something like Ener-G egg replacer. Can chia be used in the same fashion once the seeds are ground as flax?

- Is the chia composition the same as a flax egg (1 part milled flax seed to 3 parts water, in slurry)?
- Do they set the same, i.e. congeal in the same time?
- Can they be mixed for super supplement-y egg substitutes?
- What differences are there in how you make or use them, and which is preferred for different uses (if either)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With flax seeds I like using 1T of seed (ends up being 2.5T of powder) to 3T of water, and use it for thing that are suppose to be light like cake or something that needs a nutty flavor.

But with chia seeds I use exactly 1T of powder to 3T of water (ends up looking like egg whites) and use it in brownies, cookies and so on. Also chia doesn't add flavor like flax does.

**For me chia is definitely stronger.

The first time I used a chia egg I thought it was like a flax (1T seed = 2.5T powder) but I was wrong, my baked good came out very dense in the middle and tasted raw. You can still use a chia but you have to be exact.

Also a chia egg will become very thick and gloppy once it's mixed with water whereas a flax just get gooey.

Comment: Do you have any experience comparing how the gelling power of the two differs, i.e. if you use flax in lighter dishes, is it because it provides lift, or maybe chia is stronger?